# Merging two arrays into a single column in angular

Tags: angular

My json object look as below

```
{
"name": "Beans",
"location": ["AT", "BB", "ZZ"],
"container": ["Cont1", "Cont2", "Cont3"]
}
```

How can I display in HTML using ngFor a table like below

```
Name   Location/Container
Beans   AT Cont1
        BB Cont2
        ZZ Cont3
```

Please note Location/Container is single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited to add the zip function*

You could use a zip function like this [1loc.dev/zip](https://1loc.dev/#zip-multiple-arrays) and loop over the resulting array in your template.

Basically,

```js
const zip = (...arr) => Array.from({ length: Math.max(...arr.map(a => a.length)) }, (_, i) => arr.map(a => a[i])); // Taken from 1Loc.dev/##zip-multiple-arrays
this.arr =  zip(obj.location, obj.container) // becomes [["AT", "Cont1"], ["BB", "Cont2"], ["ZZ", "Cont3]]
```

You then loop over like this in your template

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of arr">
  <div>{{row[0]}} {{row[1]}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: zip in rxjs returns an observable?

Comment: Well yes. But I wasn't suggesting the `rxjs/operators/zip`. Just merging your two arrays. Follow the link I provided and it will be clearer.

Comment: I added the zip function code to my example. Please check if it answers your question now.